# Accessing a method's local variable using PowerMockito?

Tags: java, unit-testing, reflection, mockito, powermock

I want to test a private method. I know I can invoke it using PowerMock's Whitebox feature, and I can assert the final outcome of the method's execution - but is there a way I can check what one of its local variables contains somehow - sort of like setting a breakpoint (e.g. the last value before the method returns)?

The method has a few if-statements, and at the end basically combines and condenses the results into a single boolean. It would be useful to know that not only the end result but also the intermediate steps execute successfully and as intended...

Or is the only way to refactor the method and to tear it apart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerMock cannot inspect local variables - you should either break up the method to several smaller methods that could be tested independently, or, alternatively, save this value to a data member and examine it once the method's execution is over.

Comment: Saving things to field would probably break thread safety, though, wouldn't it (I'm really no expert on threading, I just imagine it drastically increases the chances)? So, really, I'd have to split it up...

Comment: If you share the object between threads - yes, it will definitely create more problems (nothing you can't solve with a proper locking mechanism, but it'll take some work - without seeing the actual code it's hard to say if it will be worth the hassle or not)